# Humanly readable keys for documents or collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have searched throughout stackoverflow looking for a way to generate numerical keys or any type of keys that are readable for the end user.

I have found multiple answers saying (you shouldn't). I get it .. but what's the alternative..

Imagine a customer having an issue regarding an Order for instance and having to spell the uid `1UXBay2TTnZRnbZrCdXh` to your call center?

Comment: Why not use the uid that is coming from the authentication process? Do you want to generate another id for your users?

Comment: @AlexMamo it’s a very messy unreadable key

Comment: Give us an example of an unmessy readable key.

Comment: I think he is concerned about the security. The generated ID's are only to identify your unique document. You can put the transaction ID's in the documents.

Comment: F1UXBay2TTnZRnbZrCdXh; imagine having to spell that to our customer support

Comment: 100504003; That's easily spelled and can be copied by anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to disassociate keys from the data they contain. The data can change, usernames, passwords, locations etc. That kind of data is very dynamic. However, links and references are more static in nature.

Suppose you have a list of followers and you're using their username as a key. If a user changes his username, not only will their entire node have the be deleted and re-written, every other occurance of that key in the database would have the changed as well. Wheras, if the key is static, the only item that changes in the child username.

So to answer the question: here's one option

```
orders
  firebase_generated_key_0
     order_number: "1111"
     ordered_by: "uid_0"
     order_amount: "$99.95"
  firebase_generated_key_1
     order_number: "2222"
     ordered_by: "uid_1"
     order_amount: "$12>95"
```

With this structure you have the order number, a link to the user that ordered it and the total amount of the order. If the customer changes what's on the order, a simple change the order_amount is done and the order stays in place.

Edit:

A comment/question asked about race conditions when writing data with Firebase. There are a number of solutions but a good starting point is with Firebase Transactions to essentially 'lock' data to prevent concurrent modifications.

See [Save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for further reading.

Comment: How would one generate the order number and guarantee it will not duplicate ?

Comment: @Faisal The order number is something your app would generate. The system I built for our company generates a sequential number but that's really up to you. Firebase only generates the key with .childByAutoId and, and you stated, is not really appropriate for an order number. As far as coding your app goes - again, that's programmers prerogative but as long as you know the last order number that was used, the next sequential one always guarantees they are not duplicated.

Comment: Great, have you considered race conditions? What's your counter for that?

Comment: Sure. That's easily done. The concept is to lock in the next sequential number so it's not re-used. You immediately write the next one in sequence, which 'locks' it in and then write any data within that node after the fact. So if the first order is in the database, 100, read that order, write node 101 which then pretty much guarantees I own 101, then at some point afterwards, I can write the child node data. The same thing works for .childByAutoId to guarantee uniqueness. See [Firebase Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

Comment: That's exactly my thought process.. I'm just scared to try it out and really wanted someone else to tell me they tried it. Your answer surely helped. I'll mark as accepted. Can you please add your comments to your answer so other people can benefit? Thanks